# Apache CSV not working properly when withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces is used

Tags: java, apache, maven, csv, format

While using Apache CSV with below maven dependency. I am getting un expected results.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and code

```
    String test = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withIgnoreSurroundingSpaces(true)
                  .format(""," "," Test1","Test2","   Test3     ");
    System.out.println(test);
```

Actual Output

```
""," "," Test1",Test2,"   Test3     "
```

Expected Output

```
"","","Test1","Test2","Test3"
```

Errors in output:
1. Extra space is not trimmed.
2. Test2 is printed without quotes is it normal behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IgnoreSurroundingSpaces ignore spaces around the double quotes. It does not trim inside the double quotes.
What you want is :

```
String test = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.builder().setTrim(true).setQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL).build()
.format(""," "," Test1","Test2","   Test3     ");
System.out.println(test);
```